# htaccess: insert index.php into the URL

Tags: .htaccess

So, I need something pretty simple, and yet I can seem to get it right anyhow. I need to redirect

http://mydomain.com/help/4/something/else/

to

http://mydomain.com/help/index.php/4/something/else

And this should work only if there is a "/help/" in the URL.

I've been trying it whole day, the last I came up to was

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(help)/
    RewriteRule . help/index.php [L]
```

but it's not working :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are rewriting the URI, but not adding on the additional parts, so whenever your rule matches, it will rewrite it as `/help/index.php`.

The following rule, without a `RewriteCond` should do the job:

```
RewriteRule ^help/(.*)$ help/index.php/$1
```

It works by only ever rewriting a URI that has `help/` as the first part of the path, then it changes that to `help/index.php/$1` - the `$1` part is comes in the braces in the matching rule.

Using your own example, http://example.com/help/4/something/else/ becomes http://example.com/help/index.php/4/something/else/.

Note that I took off the `[L]` flag, as that would stop any further rules from happening, which due to what you're rewriting to, you may not want.